# Internal error when detecting drift on AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

**Question**:

Why detecting drift, when using `iam:passrole` with `AdministratorAccess` permission fails, whereas it works when using my own super-admin user?

**Context**:

I have one user (`deployer`). This user does not have many rights, but can assume the role `deployer-cloudformation` (which only has the `AdministratorAccess` policy) for the service `cloudformation.amazonaws.com*`.

I can confirm that it all works: without this, other cloudformation tasks fails because permissions are missing.

Except for drift.

Here is an example, via the cli:

```sh
aws cloudformation detect-stack-drift --stack-name my_stack
# StackDriftDetectionId: cf63e510-a5ca-11ec-a0c3-0a6fb2671980
aws  cloudformation describe-stack-drift-detection-status --stack-drift-detection-id cf63e510-a5ca-11ec-a0c3-0a6fb2671980
```

Here is the (formatted) output:

```
DetectionStatus: DETECTION_FAILED
DetectionStatusReason:
  '{
     "Summary":"Failed to detect drift on resources [BucketA]",
     "Failures":[{"Resource":"BucketA","FailureReason":"Internal Failure"}]
  }'
DriftedStackResourceCount: 0
StackDriftDetectionId: cf63e510-a5ca-11ec-a0c3-0a6fb2671980
StackDriftStatus: IN_SYNC
StackId: arn:aws:cloudformation:<snip>
Timestamp: '2022-03-17T08:18:22.305000+00:00'
```

Note that this is a nested stack. All my nested stacks have the same error. The root stack, which only contains nested stacks (no other resources) is OK.

I cannot find anything else in the UI or with --debug. The same commands run with my own user succeeds without issue.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but I found looking in CloudTrail very useful to debug this.  Clear the read-only filter, set the source to cloudformation and enable the "Error Code" column.  Then see what pops out in the relevant time range.